# soap monitoring tridion microservices

Tags: microservices

According to this [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3D920CBF-9798-4302-9CE9-41BA4184FE20#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-43E94481-9DE0-4493-952F-6C681BC8A2BE.xml&docid=GUID-9C11248D-B5F5-4BE2-B86F-8C31303CFB75&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9C11248D-B5F5-4BE2-B86F-8C31303CFB75) I can get a SOAP response of the Tridion microservices.

I have a machine with these services and the Tridion monitoring microservice too. This is in the development platform.

For production, we are going to install 4 machines with all the microservices and we need to load balance the traffic to each machine. I'd like to know how to do a soap request using a curl, to get that XML response. The reason is to have a shell command for my load balancer. I'm doing this for other not Tridion services https://dasunhegoda.com/make-soap-request-command-line-curl/596/

My question is about the parameters to ask to Tridion microservices. I mean I have the response in the documentation, but I don't have how to do this request.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For clarity: the gven documentation topic shows that you can communicate with the Tridion Monitoring Service using SOAP; the CIS microservices are REST/OData services and don’t talk SOAP.

You could let the Tridion Monitoring Service do HTTP polling to check whether these CIS microservices seem to be “alive”, but you won’t be able to do a very extensive health check: assuming that you will have OAuth enabled on your CIS microservices, you can’t do much more than send an arbitrary HTTP Request and get an Access Denied Response back, because the Tridion Monitoring Service doesn’t support OAuth authentication/authorization.

BTW: AFAIK, the CIS microservices also expose “health check endpoints” which can be used to let a load balancer determine “health”. Again, this is a very basic check, but may be sufficient to determine whether the service is still alive.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community. The SDL monitoring service monitors SDL processes. Please refer the support link [HERE](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000007748).

For the microservices, you will have to do build your own monitor to suit your specific needs.

However, there are some community driven scripts already mentioned in the above link (using powershell and an open source java project).

If you stumble upon issues during implementation, you can update your question with relevant error message and the community will try to help you out.

Hope it helps!